# How to validate whethere a username is an email or phone number in springboot application

Tags: java, regex, spring-boot, validation, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am quite new to springboot and I am trying to create validate whether a username field is a phone number or email address in my registerDTO.

Here is how the registerDTO looks like:

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Data;

```
import javax.validation.constraints.*;

@Data
public class RegisterDTO {
    @NotNull(message= "This field cannot be blank")
    private String firstName;
    @NotNull(message="This field cannot be blank")
    private String lastName;
    private String username;

    @Digits(integer = 4, fraction = 0)
    @Pattern(regexp ="^[0-9]{4}$")
    @Size(min=4, max=4, message = "Password can only be 4 digits")
    private Integer password;
```

I want to write a custom regex that will validate if the username instance is either an email or phone number. The phone number should start with zero and not exceed 11 (maximum_length). It should throw an error if it's neither of the two.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little old but you can try to use the `@ConstraintComposition` to create your custom annotation which would be a composition of other constraint annotations.

```
@ConstraintComposition(CompositionType.OR)
@Email
@Pattern(regexp = "^0\\d{11}")
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@ReportAsSingleViolation
@Documented
public @interface EmailOrPhone {
    String message() default "Provided value was neither a valid Email nor a valid Phone number";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {  };
}
```

Then you just use your custom annotation

```
public class RegisterDTO {
    @EmailOrPhone 
    private String username;

     .....
```

Comment: I am using a multimodule project for my springboot. Thus, creating this annotation resulted in a cyclic dependency. I wrote two methods in the service where I needed it and it solved the problem.